# Weird texture rotation

Tags: node-editor, shaders, texture-coordinates

Why is the texture rotated, even tho all values are unchanged? Is there a known bug with these nodes I used? This happens with every newly added cube and even if the nodes are added from scratch.

[image]

Comment: because the Mapping node doesn't emit black and white informations but rgb informations for the 3 dimensions, you can see it if you directly plug the Mapping node into the Output node, if you want to have a horizontal or vertical b&w color, plug the Mapping into a (Convert >) Separate XYZ node, and use the Z output for example

Comment: @moonboots Thank you for the quick answer!